Python moviepy ruining video color when it's exported
I'm trying to automate the process of removing all audio from more than a thousand video.  Because the process is repetitive and software like Adobe Premier Rush requires that I have to manually mute them every single time.  Since the action of muting audio (or removing audio) is done repeatedly.  I know that it can be done entirely by the computer.
The problem is that I'm using Python's moviepy to try to automate the process and lightening the workload.  I've used function to remove sound.  The problem is that when I used function to write a new video, and I looked at the test video.  The colors did not match with the original.  The video that was output looked like it has been saturated.
I've tried different codecs, but they didn't fix the problem.  The video format is MOV.
Original color
Color after exporting
I only included a portion of the videos because I cannot reveal what it is because it's confidential.
The code that I've written is:
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

source_path = '...' # source path where the original video files is
dest_path = '...' # destination path where I want the videos without audio to go and retain the same color as the original

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(source_path) if isfile(join(source_path, f))]

# We need to test to verify that it will work.
# Use testing folders for it.
for file in onlyfiles:
    videoclip = VideoFileClip(join(source_path, file))
    new_clip = videoclip.without_audio()
    new_clip.write_videofile(join(dest_path, file), codec="libx264")

I've tried using different MPEG4, same problem.  LIBX264 is what MOV is using.  I've tried googling up how to fix the colors.  I tried using colorspace argument, but the function for writing videos didn't have that.  I tried colorsys argument.  Same problem.  I tried changing the thread numbers, changing preset, none of them fixed the color problem.
I expected to take in the original video, remove all audio, and get the exact same video but without audio in it.
The audio was removed successfully, but it degraded the video color quality.  The difference was stark.  It's as if the rich colors of the original was lost in the video without audio.  It still have some colors, but it's as if they was washed out.

I think it's because you are removing audio and re-encoding at the same time.
You can just use ffmpeg directly from your terminal, it will be faster and won't touch the video at all:
for file in *.mov; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -c copy -an "noaudio_$file"; done

If you really want it with python you can use this modification of your script:
import os
import ffmpeg

source_path = 'vids'  # path where the original video files are located
dest_path = 'done'  # path where you want to save the videos without audio

onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(source_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source_path, f))]

for file in onlyfiles:
    input_file = os.path.join(source_path, file)
    output_file = os.path.join(dest_path, file)

    # Use ffmpeg-python to remove audio and copy video without re-encoding
    (
        ffmpeg
        .input(input_file)
        .output(output_file, an=None, c='copy', map_metadata=0)  # Remove audio, copy video, keep metadata
        .run(overwrite_output=True)  # Automatically overwrite if file exists
    )


With both solutions I was able to keep 100% integrity on MOV videos.
